# Anyone know how to use FLTK straight from Notepad++?

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw, notepad++, fltk

Or if it's even possible? I downloaded Pocket C++ and I'm not too sure if it would work since it has its own version of Notepad++ in the folder it comes in.

from the pocketcpp website (https://code.google.com/p/pocketcpp/) :

"Portable and easy to use editor to write and test C++11 snippets (supported features). It integrates Notepad++ and Stephan T. Lavavej's MinGW Distro (GCC 4.8.1). You can use F9 key to compile C++ files, and Ctrl+F9 to execute the compiled program. "

I liked it because all you have to do is press F9 to compile and F10 to run on a little console that pops out right on the Notepad++ window. I just want to do the same with multiple files and using FLTK.

If anyone could clearly answer this question I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Have a look at pocketcpp\npp\plugins\config\npes_saved.txt.  At a guess, you'd have to modify the g++ command to include the fltk include path and the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the g++ call in /pocketcpp/npp/plugins/config/npes_saved.txt to include the FLTK library. It should look like this (Replace the PATH_TO_LIBRARY with the real path to the FLTK lib folder):

```
g++ -l PATH_TO_LIBRARY -o "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART)" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" -static
```

By the way: It's always a good idea to use -Wall (Display all warnings) and -g3 (Debug level maximum) for development.